# Give a list of all employees, fname, lname and dept, who make more than the average in their building

Tags: sql

but only if they work in building 400, 402 or 405

```
Select fname, lname, dept
from Employees
where in building=400
and building=402
and building =405;
```

So do I find the avg then place the building of what the numbers are in the sql or, do I use the AVG() function for finding the answer? I am suppose to use subquery, but do not know how, help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select fname, lname, dept
from Employees
where building in (400,402,405) and salary > (select avg(salary) from Employees where building in (400, 402, 405));
```

Where "salary" is the column for how much the employee makes.

Also, your in statement is wrong, I have edited for you.

Out of topic question:
Are you working in HR and trying to find some executives who earns way more the others to sack them to reduce company cost?

Comment: The code isn't quite right has you are averaging across all 3 buildings, whereas OP wants average for each build. But +1 for trying to divine the reason for the post. Maybe it's for a Redmond cost-cutting exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like:

```
SELECT fname
      ,lname
      ,dept
  FROM Employees a
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT Building
              ,AVG(Salary) BuildingAvgSalary
         FROM Empoyees
        WHERE Building IN (400,402,405)
        GROUP BY Building) b ON a.Building = b.Building
 WHERE a.Salary > b.BuildingAvgSalary
```